# Time Complexity of if inside of for loop

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

```
for(int i = 0; i < Array.length ;i++)
{
   ...
   if(s[i]>s[m]){
      m = i;
   }
}
```

What would the time complexity of this algorithm be? O(n)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < Array.length ;i++)
{
  ...
  if(s[i]>s[m]){
      m = i;
   }
 }
```

Being `n` the size of the array, and assuming that the computation done in "..." is constant, so let us label the time taken on that "..." as `c1`, then the time taken with `if(s[i]>s[m])` as `c2`, and `m = i` as c3. In the worst case-scenario this code has a time complexity of :

```
n * (c1 + c2 + c3)
```

which can be represented by `O(n)`.